# Firefox not redering graphics correctly

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I'm on Lubuntu, and I'm getting unexpected diagonal lines & triangles while using Firefox browser. Chrome, Brave works fine but not sure what's the problem with Firefox on my machine. I even tried Manjaro & Ubuntu to fix this but getting same issue everywhere.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: sometimes, somehow hovering over the elements, or changing screen sizes fixes it temporarily.

```
LXQt Desktop Toolbox - Technical Info
LXQt About Version:     0.16.0
LXQt Version:           0.16.0
Qt:                     5.15.2
Build type:             Release
```

This is really frustrating, Firefox is my favorite browser as I do Front-end development, but because of this one issue, I need to switch to another browser and have to leave all the Firefox goodies - color pickers, inspector, etc.

Comment: You've not provided any release details... I'd firstly explore the stack (which I don't know) as I had issues on some devices, that were fixed by changing stack.  The chrome & brave is useful detail, but not being Ubuntu packages, I can't look up their toolkit details easily, though stack is a required starting point (ie. what release are you using?  which stack did you choose if you're using a LTS)

Comment: ``` LXQt Desktop Toolbox - Technical Info<p>
  LXQt About Version:     0.16.0
  LXQt Version:           0.16.0
  Qt:                     5.15.2
  Build type:             Release```
is this what you asking for?

Comment: No I really meant is your Lubuntu release, which I suspect is Lubuntu 21.04 which would have told me details you provided (Lubuntu *impish* for example currently also shows the same details is also has other stack details that differ to 21.04 even though LXQt parts don't).  I don't believe it's LXQt related, closer to the kernel thus release details provide more detail than the desktop & UI toolkits .. ie. comparing https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/firefox (assuming *hirsute*) with equivalent that doesn't reveal issue).

Comment: i have mentioned in my question, that this is the problem with every linux OS i tried. Manjaro, Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Slax

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.    *Your last comment is of no value except for detail that you're likely off-topic.. without specific stack details other systems are of no use.. ie. I test using Ubuntu, Debian (testing+stable+old-s), Fedora (rawhide+stable), opensuse (tumbleweed) & the distro means ~nothing; the stack varies & that's why they're all useful for confirmation/clues on causes/fixes to issues*